# Is there a version of enblend supporting more than one CPU core / thread?

Tags: multi-processor

The task manager ksysguard tells me that only one core is being occupied fully with enblend. Sometimes enblend hops between cores, but it is apparently not developed to distribute its work among more than one core (and I've got 8 cores resp. 16  threads):

[image]

So: Is there a multi-CPU version (or patch) of enblend? My current version is 4.2 (on an OpenSUSE Leap 15.1 system). Thank you.

**UPDATE:** Firefox seems to work with `taskset`: [image]

**UPDATE #2:** Here are the linking details of my version of `enblend`:

```
╭─jacek@epica ~  
╰─➤  enblend --show-software-components
Compiler
  g++ 7.4.0

Libraries
  GSL:        2.4
  Little CMS: 2.9.0
  Vigra:      1.11.1

╭─jacek@epica ~  
╰─➤  enblend --version --verbose
enblend 4.2

Extra feature: image cache: no
Extra feature: OpenMP: no
Extra feature: OpenCL: no
```

Comment: Please run in some terminal the cmd **[enblend --version --verbose](http://enblend.sourceforge.net/enblend.doc/enblend_4.2.xhtml/enblend.html)** and add the output on your question, that cmd will definitely tell you how much processors and threads enbled is really running.

Answer (score 1):

enfuse/enblend offer source code support for partial(!) parallelization via OpenMP and/or OpenCL. You can check whether this is compiled in by using `--show-software-components`:

```
$ enfuse --show-software-components
Compiler
  g++ 9.1.0
  implementing OpenMP standard of 2015-11

Libraries
  GSL:        2.6
  Little CMS: 2.9.0
  Vigra:      1.11.1
```

This output would also list OpenCL, but it is not included in the version I have.

Keep in mind that most parts of the software probably simply cannot be parallelized.

If the binary version you currently have does not support OpenMP or OpenCL, you can simply compile your own. The repository has a good README file and you already know which features you may want to enable (from the version you currently have).